# BPEL JMS Producer and consumer instances are grouped and shown under single flow

Tags: jms, soa, weblogic12c, bpel

I am working on Bpel 12c. I have a producer BPEL process which loops for 10 times and publishes a message to a JMS queue for each iteration. I also have a BPEL process which consumes from the above JMS queue. Everything works perfectly. But my only concern is, If I got to EM Console and try to open the instance of the consumer, I am not seeing 10 separate instances instead I am seeing the instance of the producer and when I open this instance, it shows all the 10 consumers under it. This behaviour is Okay if the parent process invokes a child process. But here It is completely two separate process and why It groups like this? Imagine if there are 100 such messages, the flow will not open at all and cause memory issue. Please let me know if there is a way to modify this behaviour and Will i be able to see all 10 instances separately?

Comment: Did you check the create instance option in the BPEL receive that consume the JMS ?

Comment: Yes. Create instance option is checked and it is creating separate instances. But only problem is it shows everything grouped under the producer instance. There is no way I can view the consumer instance without opening the producer instance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like expected behaviour from Oracle SOA, if it know of an initiating composite then it shows the whole trail (Ie the produce and the consumption), it doesnt matter if you build the consumer in a seperate project/or a the same one it still links them.

Comment: Yes. Looks like. I checked the message produced by the producer and I observed that it passes additional properties like tracking.parentComponentId, tracking.compositeId, tracking.ECID etc. I infact tried to set this values to null in the Invoke operation but it doesn't considers the value. The problem with such a behaviour is, I have a loop for 100 values and each iterations it publishes a message with each value. All works good but If i try to open the flow the CPU of the server goes to 100% and the server state also goes to Warning state.

Comment: In which case, i suggest doing the same action in OSB and then invoking some custom logging to capture the information you need.